# blog id on blogspot

Tags: tags, blogspot

I want to create a button on Blogspot. The button must send me the `blog.ID` and `post.ID`. 
I can get the `post.ID` with code `<data:post.id/>` but don't know how to access `blog.ID`?

Comment: can u tell us in Brief ? u need to fetch which Blog id ?

Comment: i should be able to get the blogID of any random blog where i put my button.

Comment: i want that my button works like facebook share button. look on my image http://img43.imageshack.us/i/printdu.jpg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked on Blogspot (http://www.blogger.com) and i have edited my Blogs many times.
As far as  i know there is no attribute to fetch blog id ..
like u said you can access Post using 
`data:post.id`

I have not seen any provision for fetching  blog Id yet.
How you can see your own Blog id.

Refer this to Find Your Own BLOG id..

http://myfundoo-blog.blogspot.com/2010/05/add-reply-option-to-blogger-comments.html

But you can certainly play with other attributes like

```
data:blog.url
```

or

```
data:blog.homepageUrl
```

By the way,its not possible to other People's Blog id using Button on your blog.
You can simple find Blog Id of your own blog using [THIS](http://myfundoo-blog.blogspot.com/2010/05/add-reply-option-to-blogger-comments.html)..

Regards,
Sangram Nandkhile

Comment: anyway have any idea how that facebook share button works? here is a photo with facebook button share: http://img43.imageshack.us/i/printdu.jpg/

Comment: Not sure, but i think they work on the URL instead of ids as every post has unique and personal url..<Post.Id> is very Blogger Specific...u can try with url of the posts

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically get the blog ID with teh data tag:

```
data:blog.blogId
```

So, for example, if you insert the following code in your blogger template, it will display your blog ID:

```
<data:blog.blogId/>
```